# Encoding issue with wkhtmltopdf via Python's subprocess.Popen on Ubuntu server

Tags: python, character-encoding, debian, wkhtmltopdf

I'm having an encoding issue with `debian` / `django` / `python` / `subprocess.Popen` / `wkhtmltopdf` (not sure which part is causing the issue).

The issue is related to passing in a unicode string into `wkhtmltopdf` via Python's `subprocess.Popen` on an Amazon Ubuntu server intance.

The code:

```
popen = subrocess.Popen(
    ['wkhtmltopdf', '--header-right',  u'Copyright © 2012 Sité Náme', 'file.html', '-'],
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

On my OSX Lion development machine the page header comes out correctly with both the copyright symbol and the accented letters. On our production and test servers, not so much.

Django is returning this error on the above line: 'execv() arg 2 must contain only strings'. If I strip out the non ascii characters it does work though.

The servers are Debian GNU/Linux 6.0.4. Python version is Python 2.6.6. And I think related,      `sys.getfilesystemencoding()` returns 'ANSI_X3.4-1968' on the servers but 'UTF-8' on OSX.

I have tried adding .encode('utf-8') and various other combintation, but, although I can remove the error it just replaces the non-ascii characters with gibberish.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.